# Why django is adding an extra slash / in the last , i want to remove it?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am getting an extra slash in the end and it is giving me an error , but when I remove the slash after 2 (i.e. from last) I get the correct result.

[image]

http://127.0.0.1:8000/book/2/

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

Your pattern in the `urls.py` does not contain a trailing slash, thus it does not match.

You should end the url patterns on a slash. ([See Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/))

Additionally you probably want to activate [APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash) so that http://127.0.0.1:8000/book/2 redirects to http://127.0.0.1:8000/book/2/.
Then both versions of the url behave the same way.